# IConnectionIdFactory - what's instead in v1?

Tags: signalr

This contract is no longer available in v1.
[Extensibility](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility) has nothing similar. 
[Client - JavaScript Library, Persistent Connections](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client) claims to be able to do so, yet this code doesn't work:

```
connection.id = 'id_set_by_client_side_code';
```

Documentation says:

> Gets or sets the client id for the current connection.

Is there an issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no longer get control over the connection id in SignalR. People abused it by trying to share the connection id across multiple pages by making it something stable (which leads to buggy behavior). In SignalR 1.0, connection ids are always random. The only thing you can do is add a prefix.

Comment: So what would be a good way to correlate a client with it's data on the server side? In my case, I'm sending notification to a client, and it shouldn't go to everyone, just the client notification is intended for? An example would be handy (if you have a reference). Thanks

Comment: Query string value. You can set $.connection.hub.qs = "a=1";

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will bring the id=key to the server, but on the server, there's no way to do the following 1) var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetConnectionContext<Endpoint>();
2) context.Connection.Send(key, subscriber); For this, I need to be able to link between connectionId and key that came through querystring...

Comment: What does that have to do with GlobalHost? When you get the context outside of a hub, you never had the connection id in the first place. You need to send that to whatever is calling into Send